# 403 permission error when executing from command line client on Bigquery

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, python-requests, google-api-python-client

I have set-up gcloud in my local system. I am using Python 3.7 to insert records in big-query dataset situated in projectA. So I try it from **command line client** with the project set to projectA.  The first command I give is to get authenticated

```
gcloud auth login
```

Then I use Python 3 and get into Python mode, and I give the following commands:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

body={json input} //pass the json string here
bigquery = build('bigquery', 'v2', cache_discovery=False)
bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(projectId="projectA",datasetId="compute_reports",tableId="compute_snapshot",body=body).execute()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectA/datasets/compute_reports/tables/compute_snapshot/insertAll?alt=json returned "Access Denied: Table projectA:compute_reports.compute_snapshot: User does not have bigquery.tables.updateData permission for table projectA:compute_reports.compute_snapshot."
```

I am executing it as a user with **role/Owner** and BigQueryDataOwner permissions for the project and also added **DataEditor** to the dataset also, which has these permissions including:

- bigquery.tables.update
- bigquery.datasets.update

Still I am getting this error.

Why with my credentials am I still not able to execute insert in the big-query?

Comment: Do a `gcloud auth application-default login` and try again. Better?

Comment: Please add 'bigquery.tables.updateData' permission to the user/service account and then give a try?

Comment: tried both the options but error is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in the permissions, so the service account which was used by the python run-time, which is the default service account as set in the bash profile did not have the Bigquery dataeditor access for projectA. Once I gave the access it started working